# 2 condition in 1 where clause in Laravel Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to convert my query into laravel builder format:

This is my working query:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE tic_status_id = 65
AND (tic_escalation_date1 IS NULL OR tic_escalation_date1 < DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'))
AND (tic_escalation_date2 IS NULL OR tic_escalation_date2 < DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'))
AND (tic_escalation_date3 IS NULL OR tic_escalation_date3 < DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'))
```

I'm trying to use whereNull and orWhere but It's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping) to constrain the or where.

> Passing a Closure into the where method instructs the query builder to
>   begin a constraint group. The Closure will receive a query builder
>   instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be
>   contained within the parenthesis group.

Then, inside the constrain you can use [whereNull()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNull) to add a "where null" clause to the query, and [orWhereDate()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate) to add a "or where date" statement to the query. Note the whereDate method will take the date part out from the [datetime](https://php.net/DateTimeInterface) expression.

```
DB::table('tickets')
            ->where('tic_status_id', '=', 65)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date1')
                      ->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date1', '<', '2019-06-22 13:00:00');
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date2')
                      ->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date2', '<', '2019-06-22 13:00:00');
            })
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date3')
                      ->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date3', '<', '2019-06-22 13:00:00');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: What's the difference between orWhereDate and orWhere?

Comment: The whereDate method could be used to compare a column's value against a date,  takes the date part out from a datetime expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
    $tickets = DB::table('tickets');
    $tickets->where('tic_status_id', 65);
    $tickets->where(function($query){
        $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date1');
        $query->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date1', '<', DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'));
    });
    $tickets->where(function($query){
        $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date2');
        $query->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date2', '<', DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'));
    });
    $tickets->where(function($query){
        $query->whereNull('tic_escalation_date3');
        $query->orWhereDate('tic_escalation_date3', '<', DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00'));
    });
    $ticket_data = $tickets->get();
```

Please refer [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) for more information. You can use "orWhere" in place of "orWhereDate" if you have a column other then "DateTime" type.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

**Method One**

```
$query = DB::table( 'tickets')
            ->where( 'tic_status_id' ,'=',65)
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date1')
            ->orWhere( 'tic_escalation_date1', '<', "DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00')")
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date2')
            ->orWhere( 'tic_escalation_date2', '<', "DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00')")
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date3')
            ->orWhere( 'tic_escalation_date3', '<', "DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00')");
```

**Method Two** `I am Not Sure About the this query will Work Fine`

```
$query = DB::table( 'tickets')
            ->where( 'tic_status_id' ,'=',65)
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date1')
            ->orWhereDate( 'tic_escalation_date1', '<', "('2019-06-22 13:00:00')")
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date2')
            ->orWhereDate( 'tic_escalation_date2', '<', "DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00')")
            ->whereNull( 'tic_escalation_date3')
            ->orWhereDate( 'tic_escalation_date3', '<', "DATE('2019-06-22 13:00:00')");
```